# UninstallRun Check function execution during uninstall

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I'm writing an Inno Setup installer, which can be installed multiple times and installs third party products as well. The third party products are needed for every installation, so when uninstalling my app, I would run a check function on an `[UninstallRun]` entry to see if there are any more instances of my app still on the system. If so, than I would not remove the third party products (only the uninstallation of the last instance of my app would uninstall these...).

The problem is that it seems, that the `[UninstallRun]` check function executed and evaluated during installation and not uninstallation (as the uninstall data is built during install). This means that if I uninstall the firstly installed instance of my app, than it removes the third party products (because the time of the installation of the first there were no other instances of my app).

Is there a way to tell Inno Setup to execute the check function of the `[UninstallRun]` section during, and only at uninstall?
If not any ideas how to achieve the required behaviour?

Comment: I would call it a bug since there's no need those check functions to be evaluated at installation time. Their entries never get executed at installation time so there's no need to evaluate their checks. I thought I could help you by suggesting a conditional running of your functionality if the `IsUninstaller` returns True. What is worse, the `IsUninstaller` function returns False even from uninstaller. I don't have time now to go deeper, but I feel there's something wrong here. (btw. I'm having v.5.5.4)

Comment: It seems that is is by design: http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=99482&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#99482
Odd...

Comment: Uhm, so then all the check values are evaluated when the uninstaller is being created. This is very misleading and I think that many people expects to conditionaly run something depending on the actual situation of a certain system state when the uninstaller runs, not when the application is installed (and uninstaller created). In this situation I'm for removing the `Check` parameter from the `[UninstallRun]` section hence it may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: [There *is* a good reason for it](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=99487&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#99487).

Answer (score 3):

There is not.

However, you can write some `[Code]` that will execute at uninstall time.  Typically something along these lines:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then begin
    if ShouldUninstallComponentX() then begin
      UninstallComponentX();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You will need to fill in the ComponentX functions yourself of course, and you will want to add error checking etc as appropriate.

You still need to take care when doing auto-uninstalls of third party products, though.  Unless there's something unique to your applications about the way they were installed (eg. a custom instance name in the case of a database server) then you might still inadvertently uninstall the product when it was still in use by some other application, or it might uninstall it when you still needed it.

If it's something big enough to be a "product" then it ought to have its own entry in Programs and Features -- and if that's the case then it may be best to leave it to the user to decide when to remove it, either by never automatically removing it yourself, or by asking the user at the time that you think it's safe to uninstall (ie. when the last copy of your apps is removed) whether they really want to or not.

Smaller shared library components typically adopt a different approach; instead of running a full install/uninstall program you would include the libraries directly in `[Files]` and use the `sharedfile` flag to track when they're safe to remove.  (This relies on all applications doing the same thing, of course -- but this works even for applications that do not use Inno as their installer.)

Ideally, if the product is intended to be used as a shared component it should have documentation on how to properly determine when no other applications require it.